# Using stockPortfolio without Yahoo Finance

Tags: r

I am very new to R and i want to use the stockPortfolio package to model stocks( SIM, CC, MGM). Since Yahoo finance is not available for FTSE100 data (its been disabled), i have my data as a *.csv file.
How do i use stockPortfolio library with my data without getting error like
"Error in stockModel(data, drop = 31) : 
  The "stockReturns" variable is not recognized."
Thank you.

Comment: To be of any help you have to show us the structure of your `csv` file and how you tried to import it into R.

Comment: I have imported my csv file into r using read.csv. The file contains monthly returns of stocks. Date ADM AAL ANTO AZN
01/06/2011 0.006501182 -0.033327992 -0.042428676 0.065217391
01/07/2011 -0.017615972 0.028344107 0.084797555 -0.019152276

Comment: I have imported my csv file into r using data <- read.csv("monthly_returns.csv", header=TRUE) The file contains monthly returns of stocks for 30 tickers. Date ADM AAL ANTO AZN
01/06/2011 0.006501182 -0.033327992 -0.042428676 0.065217391. The following input comes up with an error "stockReturns" variable is not recognized."                                                                                       singleindex <- stockModel(Returns, model='SIM', index=31, shortSelling ="y", Rf=0.0025). Thank you

Comment: Looks like your Date variable is in the wrong format.Should be "YYYY-mm-dd". Before you apply the data to the function, make sure that the Date variable is imported correctly and recognized as class `Date`.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the date variable but i'm still getting the error message.